# Handling multi language website

Tags: php, database

I have a multi-language website that communicates with a database, which contains language-specific translations.

For example, a table gender has 10 rows, and each row indicates a language.

```
+---------+-----------+-----+
| English | French    | etc |
| Male    | Masculine | ... |
+---------+-----------+-----+
```

Some languages (like Chinese, Greek, Turkish, Spanish, Russian, etc. have characters outside of latin1,  and when i read the data from the database on my site they come out with `?` and garbled symbols *(mojibake)*

So, how do I fix this?

I know i need to use certain collation on the db and add the specific meta charset tag but it's still not working.

```
 cp1256 | Windows Arabic          | cp1256_general_ci (it's not giving me the correct arabic solution.)
 gbk    | GBK Simplified Chinese  | gbk_chinese_ci    (it's not giving me the correct chinese solution.)
```

Comment: http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: While I edit this, have you considered using UTF-8 (Unicode) for all of these?

Comment: or ucs2 if you use mssql

Comment: which dbms? which collation do you use? did you try utf-8?

Comment: i changed all the collactuon to utf-8-general-ci

Comment: still when i get the info from the data base they are coming out like this ?? eave soo the information writin in the php code directly are coming out perfectly correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole load of areas of your system that need to be considered when looking at multi-lingual systems.

You need to to ensure that you are using a suitable character encoding throughout your system. In most cases, the best choice of character encoding is UTF-8. (There are some instances where UTF-8 is insufficient, for which cases there is UTF-16, but these cases are few and far between, and PHP will struggle with UTF-16 anyway, so in general stick with UTF-8 for everything and you'll be fine).

You need to make sure you're using the same character encoding in the following places:

- Your database tables.
- Your web server.
- Your PHP source code.

The database is easy to deal with: just make sure all tables are created with UTF-8 encoding for their charset. Job done.

Collation is less relevant -- this specifies the sort order. This does matter of course, but does not have any relevance to the garbled text display you're seeing. (it's worth saying that some characters are sorted differently in different languages, so it's virtually impossible to pick a collation mode that will suit everyone if you need to support multiple languages in a single table, but I wouldn't get too worried about this for now).

The web server is relatively simple too, as long as you're comfortable with Apache config (or whatever server software you're using). You need to ensure that all pages output to the browser are sent using UTF-8 encoding.

Finally, your PHP source code...

Firstly, you should make sure you're editing the actual PHP code files in UTF-8 mode. Otherwise, any you may have trouble if you have any extended characters written in your code.

Secondly, be aware that a number of PHP's standard string handling functions are "not multi-byte aware". This means that they don't work correctly with extended character sets. For example, `strlen()` will return the number of bytes the string takes up in memory. This will be incorrect if your string includes characters that take up more than one byte. Fortunately, PHP also supplies a set of multi-byte functions to resolve this. So for example, instead of using `strlen()`, use `mb_strlen()`. The PHP manual gives more detail about the exact functions available and when to use them.

Also, make sure that you handle any incoming posted data with the correct character set as well.

Hopefully that will help you. The key here is to ensure that your system uses a consistent character set throughout all its layers. Problems with weird-looking encoding errors tend to happen when one layer in your system is using a different character set to the others. Make sure they're all the same (and preferably UTF-8), and you should deal with your garbled character problems.

Comment: i tried what u said it worked for stuff writin in the php code like  出生国家</b></td><td>".$info3['chin']."</td>

Comment: but the caracters that come from databse $info3['chin'] that is inserted in the databse (阿尔及利亚) like this ! it coming out (????) the collaction is all utf-8 so dont know whats else to change :/ thx in advance

Comment: @user1700243 - Set the character-set of the connection object `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');` before you make the query. For other databases you can follow the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Collation is only used for sorting purposes while charset is used for storage.  Apparently you're using the `latin1` charset, which is interesting.  Many would suggest to go with a `utf-8` charset, so you will have to convert all of your data to that charset now.  Personally, I would use binary data (`binary` vs. `char`, `varbinary` vs. `varchar`, `blob` vs. `text`).  This is only a problem if you need accurate sorting (collation) as binary sorting is different.

Comment: Why would you use binary storage for textual data, instead of an appropriate encoding?

Comment: @Ianzz there is no appropriate encoding; many different languages are being stored in the same table simultaneously.

Comment: So UTF-8 is inappropriate? How would you handle binary data in different, unspecified encodings on the application side?

Comment: @lanzz - as soon as you are storing multiple languages in a single table, you have a problem with collation/sorting, because even among languages that share the same symbols, there are differences in the sort order.

Comment: @lanzz - no, it doesn't. the point is that there isn't a good solution. (at least not when it comes to sorting)

Comment: @SDC So ExplosionPills' solution sacrifices maintainability (if you ever find yourself needing to manipulate the data by hand, which could be helped by being able to _read_ the data in the CLI client or PHPMyAdmin) for exactly zero gain?

Comment: @lanzz - I agree with you; there's no real merit in storing text data as a binary blob. I was only really trying to expand on what he said about collation not being much use when you've got multiple languages.

Comment: @Ianzz it doesn't sacrifice maintainability; if you print the data it will print as whatever character was stored based on the charset of whatever is doing the printing.  That is, if you're using a browser and the specified charset is UTF-8 it will print it as UTF-8 and be fully readable.  The alternative solution of using a text column with UTF-8 as the charset is also viable, but if sorting is unnecessary it's less efficient to convert data of an unspecified charset to UTF-8 on every insert instead of storing it raw.

Comment: If you're working directly with the database and do `SELECT blob_column FROM table`, there is _no encoding at all_ that can display readable content for all rows from your binary column.

Answer (score 1):

You should use specific tables for traductions, not columns. In this case you can specify the charset for every table.

At this moment you have:

```
+---------+-----------+-----+
| English | French    | etc |
| Male    | Masculine | ... |
+---------+-----------+-----+
```

You should have:

```
gender_en
+-----------+--------------+
| id_gender |       value  |
+-----------+--------------+
|         1 |         Male |
|         2 |       Female |
+-----------+--------------+

gender_es
+-----------+--------------+
| id_gender |       value  |
+-----------+--------------+
|         1 |       Hombre |
|         2 |        Mujer |
+-----------+--------------+

gender_fr
.....
```

And so on

Comment: but i got like 10 types of tables with 10 langages so if i do so i will have 100 tables 
! eaven so how to get the info from the dabase without having ??$$ and weird stuff thats the proble:S thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to use UTF-8 for the whole website. UTF-8 can work with all known characters of other encodings. If you are using mysql, it is important that you tell the connection object to use UTF-8, before you make a query. I wrote a short article of how you can use [UTF-8 in PHP and MySQL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).

The collation is not the same as the charset, it only defines how two values are compared (e.g. for sorting).